# Create View by Left join on multiple columns with OR

Tags: mysql, sql, join, view, left-join

I am trying to create a view from two tables by left joining on two columns: `t1.recipient_email = t2.username` or  `t1.created_by = t2.id`. As shown in pseudocode below, I want the first t2.name to be the recipient_name and second t2.name to be sender_name. I can't think of the correct way to achieve this.

```
CREATE VIEW  emailsent_log_view
(id_email_que_log, date_sent, recipent_email, recipient_name, send_status, sender_name)
 AS
SELECT
    t1.id,
    t1.date_send,
    t1.recipient_email,
    t2.name, --recipient_name: corresponds with t1.recipient_email = t2.username
    t1.send_status,
    t2.name --sender_name: correspond with t1.created_by = t2.id

    FROM email_que_log AS t1
    LEFT JOIN user_account as t2
    ON  t1.recipient_email = t2.username
    OR t1.created_by = t2.id
```

Comment: Why do you want a view anyway?

Comment: I want a view so that it would be easier for applications such as 'Grocery crud' to fetch data from a single view rather than multiple tables

Comment: I suspect that Applications generally find both methods equally straightforward. To my mind, views in MySQL serve almost no useful purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you guessed, you can't pick and choose which row joins to which row with an `or` condition like that. The way to solve such issues is to join the table **twice**, once for each need:

```
CREATE VIEW  emailsent_log_view
(id_email_que_log, date_sent, recipent_email, recipient_name, send_status, sender_name)
AS
SELECT
    eql.id,
    eql.date_send,
    eql.recipient_email,
    res.name AS reciever, -- From the first join
    eql.send_status,
    snd.name AS sender -- From the second join
FROM
    email_que_log AS eql
LEFT JOIN 
    user_account AS res ON eql.recipient_email = res.username
LEFT JOIN 
    user_account AS snd ON eql.created_by = snd.id
```

Comment: Thanks @Mureinik. Your solution is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Note that any application accessing this view will be unable to distinguish between res.name and snd.name

Comment: @Strawberry good point. Edited the post to add aliases and make them distinguishable